# doxygen - WARN_AS_ERROR for certain areas only

Tags: doxygen

It's possible to set `WARN_AS_ERROR=YES` for certain areas only?

But I would like to produce the documentation for the other areas too.

```
--dir1 -> WARN_AS_ERROR=true  + generation in case of no warnings
  --a.h
  --b.h
--dir2 -> WARN_AS_ERROR=false + generation
  --c.h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not directly possible when you create the documentation on one go, so for dir1 and dir2.

When using tag files and creating first e.g. dir1 including creation of a tag file with the setting of `WARN_AS_ERROR=YES` and after that creating the documentation for dir2 using the created tag file and using `WARN_AS_ERROR=NO`. It is possible.

See also the documentation of:

- `GENERATE_TAGFILE`
- `TAGFILES`